# .append of CSS doesn't affect iframe in IE/Edge

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, microsoft-edge

I have an iframe that I need to append CSS into. It is working on all browsers except IE/Edge. I need to hide the header in this iframe and I am using .append to do so.

I have tried `.append("<style type='text/css'> #header {display: none;}</style>');` I also tried -ms-high-contrast media queries.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('iframe').load( function() {
        $('iframe').contents().find("head")
            .append("<style type='text/css'> #header {display: none 
 !important;}</style>"); 
    });
});
```

I expect my div with an id of #header to be hidden on IE/Edge browsers, within the iframe.

Comment: How is the header works in your iframe?Could you please share detailed code like html code? This will be easier for us to reproduce the issue and help you.

Comment: This is the page I am iframing (https://www.drury.edu/evening-and-online/majors-minors-even). I am trying to hide the div with the class "header".

This is my html code for the iframe:
<div class="slideToggleBox" style="display: none;">
 <iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.drury.edu/evening-and-online/majors-minors-even" target="" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot simpler to modify the #header div directly, like this:

`$("iframe").contents().find("#header").css({display:"none"});`

or the non-jQuery version:

`document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument.querySelector("#header").style.display="none";`

Note that `contents()` won't work if your own page is not at drury.edu. Browsers won't let you frame someone else's website and then monkey with it.